# C Program abruptly ends for some inputs

Tags: c

This program is supposed to find sum of all the prime numbers less than 
or equal to N. But for some random inputs it gives run time error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int j,i,t;
    long long int n, sum=0;
    scanf("%d",&t);

    while(t--)
    {
        scanf("%lld",&n);
        int *a=malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
        a[0]=0;
        a[1]=0;

        for(i=2; i<=n; i++)
        {
            a[i]=i;
        }

        for(i=2; i<=n; i++)
        {
            for(j=2; i*j<=n; j++)
            {
                a[i*j]=0;
            }

            if(a[i])
            {
                sum+=a[i];  
            }
        }

        printf("%lld\n",sum);
        sum=0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: You don't even know if any of your `scanf()` calls work.  Check the return values.  Also, you need to provide a lot more information or this question will be closed as off-topic.  "Why isn't my code working?" is not an appropriate question here.

Comment: And for which input _exactly_?

Comment: The two for cycles cause undefined behavior, because of out of bounds array access.

Comment: For inputs (5, 10) it works as expected. but if you give the same input in reverse order like (10, 5) it terminates. why?

Answer (score 4):

```
malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
```

This allocates place for `n` `int`s, starting with index `0`, the last valid one at index `n - 1`.

```
    for(i=2; i<=n; i++)
    {
        a[i]=i;
```

This writes to indexes `2..n`, which includes `n`, which is outside the bounds of the array.

The same also happens in

```
        for(j=2; i*j<=n; j++)
        {
            a[i*j]=0;
```

if `n` is divisible by `i`